# Where does dissatisfaction/ingratitude fall in Big Five traits?

Tags: personality

Example: Someone scores 92/100 in an exam, or gets 3.6/4.0 GPA, or accepted by their 2nd choice university (out of 5 ranked preferences). But is dissatisfied with the outcome, and thinks:

This is not "good enough". I wish I had received better outcomes.
Feels bad/sad that they didn't get accepted at choice #1 university.

Another person has objectively worse outcomes but is happy and jubilant:

85/100: Wow, I got over 80, cool!

Accepted by their 5th/last choice university: This is awesome, I got in!

Question: How do the above fit in the Big Five personality traits?
It doesn't seem like Conscientious, Openness, Extraversion, Agreeableness or Neuroticism would explain this tendency to be satisfied and easily pleased vs. mostly being discontent and wanting more and better.

Comment: My guess is that this would be most correlated with neuroticism, as it involves the handling of a (presumably irrational) emotional instability concerning their future. A certain amount of high standards/inflexibility produced by conscientiousness could be related, too. Much of the rest might simply be too contextual to a person's values and goals (and not personality per se) to judge objectively. But research results to test something like this could be interesting.

Comment: Hi Feryll, that's interesting. How about controlling and bossy behavior in relationships? What aspects of the Big Five might cover that? Or would we need to go to the HEXACO model for that?

Comment: Hi, you might want to think about "maximizing", "regret", "response to performance feedback", and "lack of gratitude" as different concepts.  I think "dissatisfaction" could be one response to performance feedback.